# What happens if i delete an entity that has already been trained

Tags: watson-knowledge-studio

I want to delete an entity out of 4 other entities on knowledge studio, ibm watson but im scared it will break it?

Will my other entities still work ?

Answer (score 0):

If you already executed ML training and have a ML model, it is good way to save current trained model as a version before you delete the entity type (by "Create Version" button in "Machine Learning Model" > "Versions" view). The saved ML model is not affected by entity deletion, meaning that the model contains the entity type.
Note that the non-saved trained model is affected the entity type deletion.

The other entity types and their annotations still work even after the entity type deletion. Additionally, you can revert the saved model and entity definitions by promoting the saved version (by "Promote" button in the Versions view).